# How can i run a query on a mysql table using php arrays as values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a mysql table that contains records of user's interest. e.g

```
id  | username |    email     | interest
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2   | lynx     | lynx@exm.com | sports, business, entertainment
```

With the example above, assuming I'm searching for records of user's with interest in entertainment and the values used to query the database contains array values. eg

```
array('movies', 'games', 'entertainment');
```

With that array, i should be able to get lynx records because they are interested in entertainment.
I've tried using the IN Operator for MySQL but didn't get any result.  I also converted the field to fulltext just to use the LIKE operator but didn't get any results too.

Comment: MySQL Full Text Search (FTS) uses the `MATCH ... AGAINST` syntax; `LIKE` is not FTS functionality.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Term Solution

The `interest` data is denormalized, so you're looking at using the [FIND_IN_SET operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to search it:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(@interest, t.interest) > 0
```

`@interest` represents a single value from the array you posted.  IE: "entertainment"

### Long Term Solution

The tables need to be restructured to be normalized data - that means moving the `interests` out of the `USERS` table using:

### USER_INTERESTS

- user_id (pk, fk to USERS.user_id)
- interest_id (pk, fk to INTERESTS.interest_id)

### INTERESTS

- interest_id (primary key)
- description

Here's the query you'd use in that situation:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN USER_INTERESTS ui ON ui.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN INTERESTS i ON i.interest_id = ui.interest_id
 WHERE i.description = @interest
```

To search based on multiple interests:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN USER_INTERESTS ui ON ui.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN INTERESTS i ON i.interest_id = ui.interest_id
 WHERE i.description IN (@interest1, @interest2, @interest3)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply.. i'll give the long-term solution a try. thanks again